# Where exactly(!) does the stack pointer point to on x86-CPUs? TO the top element or RIGHT BEHIND it?

Tags: assembly, stack, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, stack-pointer

In some tutorials it is said that the stack pointer points TO the top element of the stack:

```
+-------------+
|    stack    |
+-------------+
| top element |  <-- esp
+-------------+
```

In others it is said that it points RIGHT BEHIND it, so to the first memory address which can be written to when the stack grows.

```
+-------------+
|    stack    |
+-------------+
| top element | 
+-------------+  <-- esp
```

On this german Wickipedia site
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(Computer)#Stapelregister
it is said that both versions exist and that it depends on the CPU architecture.

My question is, how is it on x86-CPUs? And does it also depend on the operating system?

Comment: Your second drawing is misleading because it gives the impression that the SP points in between elements. You should probably add an extra (empty) stack slot to that drawing if that's what you mean.

Comment: I did put "x86 stack sp" into google, and first hit was: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/   (but that looks as excessive article for "totally dumb" including many pictures). [Description of inner workings of `push`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_269.html) should be more than enough. (I.e. I'm blaming you of very low effort, then again maybe you just hit all the wrong results from search somehow).  ... and no, the CPU doesn't care about OS, and x86 can't be reconfigured in this detail, it's fixed.

Comment: x86 is a "full descending" type stack, so first diagram. Stack pointer points to the top element and stack grows down.

Comment: See [the ISA reference manual for `push`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html).  Decrement R/ESP, then store, so `qword [rsp]` is the data you just pushed.

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for the links. They show what I assumed as the right answer, but I was irritated by some tutorials, where it was not shown in that exact way. But yea of course still more research might have cleared it up more, but doesn't this is the case for most of the questions asked in forums? I researched my own for hours when I count the time I was watching the tutorials. No offense, I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: @Jester and Peter Thank you.

Comment: well.. I didn't downvote, because it kinda makes sense this question, if you were not able to tell from obviously several web pages, then you have real struggle. Although it shouldn't have happened in the first place, maybe don't be **that** visual and try also add more text description, the `push` mechanics are well described. And when you want to be visual, be visual in debugger. It took me 2 minutes from taking some example 32b asm, add `push 0x12345678` as first instruction, and open it in debugger and check myself how the stack memory and `esp` is affected. Debugger is final referee ;).

Comment: @Ped7g O.k., I will use a debugger, although it won't be 2 minutes for me, because I have never ever written one single line of assembly code and have not really an idea how to do that, yet. But I will learn it. Everyone has his first time ;-)

Comment: sure, that's fair. As you will probably wonder about many other things while learning assembly, definitely get some set of working: assembler, example code (hello world should be enough for start) and debugger. And try it few times inside-out to make sure you can step into the example and watch how it works, even if you don't understand the code fully. Then you can any time you wish add some bogus experiment at the entry point, like that `push 0x12345678` and check in debugger what happens and how the official instruction description fits that (should fit perfectly, if not = misunderstanding).

Comment: @akindperson: There are *many* bad tutorials.  It's a lot of work to write a good one, and it seems a lot of them were written by people who only just learned asm and are still confused about some things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you are in 32b x86 mode, and you have memory from address 100 to 200 reserved as stack (unreal, too low, would clash with IVT, but will do for this example). There are already some values in stack, so `esp` is 160.

Now the "top of the stack value" occupies memory at addresses 160, 161, 162 and 163 (four bytes, because in 32b mode the single value in stack is 32b = 4B big), let's say there's stored value `0xaabbccdd`.

If you now do `push 0x12345678`, the CPU will first subtract 4 from `esp` -> new `esp = 156; (160-4)`. And then it will write the 32b value, broken down in little-endian way as four bytes: `mem[156] = 0x78, mem[157] = 0x56, mem[158] = 0x34, mem[159] = 0x12`.

Now if you will execute `mov eax,[esp]`, it will load 32 bit value from address 156, which means it will compose 32b value from four bytes at addresses 156, 157, 158, 159 into `dword` value 0x12345678.

Finally when you will view the memory in debugger after the push, viewing it from `ss:esp` address, it will contain these bytes (hexa):

```
0000009C:  78 56 34 12 DD CC BB AA ....
```

(0x9C = 156 = address where the memory view starts). The `esp` points at the first byte of the value, which is considered to be "top of stack".

Or when you switch memory view to display `dword` values, to avoid the little-endian composing in head, it will show:

```
0000009C:  12345678 AABBCCDD ....
```